# YouTube Api v3: list playlist videos

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I use folowwing code to list Channel's video:

```
String URL="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=25&key={Your_API_KEY}";
```

It works well, lists 50 videos from my channel. Now i want to list my playlist's videos. I tried following code adding 'playlistId':

```
String URL="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&maxResults=25&key={Your_API_KEY}";
```

But it doesn't work....any ideas ?

Comment: did you get the playlist url, which youtube gave ?

Comment: Android Youtube App

Comment: Youtube>Library>Playlists>playlistName>Share>copy link.

Answer (score 2):

First add Youtube dependency in your `build.gradle`:

> compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev189-1.23.0'

For me it seems wrong url for playlist. **[Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)** has shared sample code for listing playlist video of specific playlist of all playlist video of specific channel. Here is sample snippet for listing video from specific playlist.

```
YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();
try {
    HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails");
    parameters.put("maxResults", "25");
    parameters.put("playlistId", "PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE");

    YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest = youtube.playlistItems().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
    if (parameters.containsKey("maxResults")) {
        playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.setMaxResults(Long.parseLong(parameters.get("maxResults").toString()));
    }

    if (parameters.containsKey("playlistId") && parameters.get("playlistId") != "") {
        playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.setPlaylistId(parameters.get("playlistId").toString());
    }

    PlaylistItemListResponse response = playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.execute();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

**Or,** as per your current implementation, change url as below

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&key={MY_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I didn't find "YouTube" class.

Comment: Where i can put the playlist Id, and how to retrive   video's infos. Can you please provide full code.

Comment: @NijwmsaBoro You didn't bothered to visit link, which I attached in my post ? Anyway, I have updated the post. So, please have a look.

Comment: @NijwmsaBoro Don't forget to upvote and accept, so that it will be helpful for others in future

Comment: how to get views of each item?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for the playlist API request instead of search.

```
String URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&id={PLAYLIST_ID}&maxResults=25&key={Your_API_KEY}";
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/playlists

please follow this blog